# How to Automatic Start JasperReports Server On Ubuntu After Restart or Start Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

How to automatic start JasperReports Server on Ubuntu after restart or start ubuntu

INFO.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

JasperReports Server 5.6.0

I'm use manual start cd /jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0/ ./ctlscript.sh start

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: You  need to create an `upstart` job.  There is an example on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22099/want-to-make-an-upstart-script-need-help-and-advice).

Comment: Instead of answering your question by editing it, add it as an new answer.  It makes more sense for future readers and you may also get reputation points if someone finds your answer useful. It's [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit WEB :http://sochinda.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/adding-jasperserver-as-service-in-ubuntu/

I Make automatic :

Create file called jasperserver in init.d

```
#sudo nano /etc/init.d/jasperserver
```

Insert this text:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: jasperserver
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start JasperServer at boot time
# Description: Enable service provided by JasperServer.
### END INIT INFO

JASPER_HOME="/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0"

case "$1" in
 start)
 if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
 echo "Starting JasperServer"
 $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh start
 fi
 ;;
 stop)
 if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
 echo "Stopping JasperServer"
 $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh stop
 fi
 ;;
 restart)
 if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
 echo "Restarting JasperServer"
 $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh restart
 fi
 ;;
 status)
 if [ -f $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh ]; then
 $JASPER_HOME/ctlscript.sh status
 fi
 ;;
 *)
 echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
 exit 1
 ;;
esac
```

Set jasperserver in init.d as execute permission

```
> #sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/jasperserver
```

Update jserperserver as default service in Ubuntu

```
> #sudo update-rc.d jasperserver defaults
```

can use command as

> `#sudo service jasperserver start`

and Add service /etc/rc1.d/K20jasperserver in startup application Ubuntu.

Finish reboot Ubuntu.

Will Automaitc start.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer worked excellently, but it is useful to note that you need to set your Jasper Server home directory:

```
JASPER_HOME="/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0"
```

in the startup script.  If you do not change it to match your version, the script fails silently when run.